# Slicing a 4-D array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I created a numpy array called 'd' and then reshape it to get 'd1' as follows:-

```
d=np.arange(32)
d1=d.reshape(2,2,2,4)
```

The numpy array 'd1' looks like:-

```
[[[[ 0  1  2  3]
   [ 4  5  6  7]]

  [[ 8  9 10 11]
   [12 13 14 15]]]


 [[[16 17 18 19]
   [20 21 22 23]]

  [[24 25 26 27]
   [28 29 30 31]]]]
```

I want to slice and extract this array so as to get two 1-D arrays as follows:-

```
[[13 14]
 [17 18]]
```

I'm new to numpy and barely started 2 days ago. Am able to do some basic stuff with indexing and slicing. However this one has me stumped for hours. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Do we have to guess the rule or? More seriously, what characterizes such selection: `[[13 14] [17 18]]`?

Comment: the output you show looks like a 2x2 array (not "two 1-D arrays"). Also, what's the logic of selection? 2x2 at the center? Something else?

Comment: okay so if its a 2x2 array, then what should be the dimension of d1? And ya, its a 2-D array.

Comment: `d1` is a 4-D array, given your `.reshape(2,2,2,4)` (four dimensions).

Comment: yes. I get your point. d1 is a 4-D array with shape(2,2,2,4). So its a 4-D array which basically has two 3-D arrays, four 2-D arrays, eight 1-D arrays all with 4 columns.  That's my understanding of it.

Comment: So you want `d1[0,1,1,1:3]` and `d1[1,0,0,1:3]`.  Together `d1[[0,1],[1,0],[1,0],1:3]]`

Answer (score 1):

If your selection is arbitrary, and you just want a way to get `[[13, 14], [17, 18]]`. Then, here is a possible solution:

1. first reshape your nd-array to a 2D array

   ```
   >>> d.reshape(8, 4)
   array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
          [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
          [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
          [12, 13, 14, 15],
          [16, 17, 18, 19],
          [20, 21, 22, 23],
          [24, 25, 26, 27],
          [28, 29, 30, 31]])
   ```
2. slice properly along both remaining axes:

   ```
   >>> d.reshape(8, 4)[3:5, 1:3]
   array([[13, 14],
          [17, 18]])
   ```

---

Alternatively you can always unravel the indices into `d` shape and index the array with those:

```
>>> idx = np.unravel_index([13, 14, 17, 18], d.shape)
(array([0, 0, 1, 1]),
 array([1, 1, 0, 0]),
 array([1, 1, 0, 0]),
 array([1, 2, 1, 2]))

>>> d[idx]
array([13, 14, 17, 18])
```

Comment: okay. So basically you converted the 'd' array into 8 1-D arrays thus making a final 2-D array which is easier to slice. That seems a good idea. But I was just curious whether it can be done in its current shape. Thanks btw.

Comment: Reshaping is a basic operation that does not require data copying. I doubt you will find another way without creating a view of the original array.

Comment: Reshaping is a basic operation that does not require data copying. I doubt you will find another way without creating a view of the original array. Anyhow, I have added an alternative solution using [`np.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html).